# Options for In-memory databases (Open source and Java-based)

Tags: java, web-services, caching, jetty, in-memory-database

I've a web app that makes external web service calls on behalf of it's clients. I want to cache the data returns by some web services in the web app so that other clients can reuse this data and run filters and queries on this cached data.

The current architecture of the web app uses Apache Camel, Spring and Jetty. I'm looking for options (pros/cons) of in-memory database options.

Comment: which option did you end using

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hazelcast (Java API) - you can distribute the in-memory datagrid (with map, multimap, sets, lists, queues, topics) over multiple nodes very easily & use load/store interface implementation with a disk based DB.  You can do something similar with EHCache.

Redis is another option (use the Java client to access it).  You can simply configure the conf file to write data to disk (or avoid it altogether) & should not have to write your own load/store classes.

Besides these, there are a number of options you could use.  Not sure if you are only looking at open source options, looking at distributed options or not.
Hope it helps.

Comment: My goal to temp store the results of my web service call in a in memory database so that I can then preform some operations (filtering, joins) and other clients can reuse them if they need the same data. I want to avoid a disk-based database because there I've the addition disk I/O overhead. Currently, I'm looking for open source solutions and they don't have to be distributed.

Comment: if you do not need to store the data on disk, you can choose not to implement the store interface in Hazelcast (or simply turn off disk writing in the redis.conf file).  If you are looking for a more SQL like interface, you could look into H2 in-memory database.  If you are ok with using collections, I would recommend Redis/Hazelcast/EHCache.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using [MemCached](http://memcached.org/)?  It is not a database, but a caching system you can control from inside your application.

---

Here are a few more thoughts about in-memory databases.  First almost every modern RDBMS has a memory caching system inside it.  The more memory you give to the database server (and configure it for caching) the more that it will store in memory for later.  If you put together a system with enough memory to cache all the tables, you will have an "in memory" cache without the overhead of another database.

Most total "in memory" databases are used for high volume/large data systems where performance is totally key.  And, because they are for extreme performance systems, you are going to pay for them.  Or more specifically, pay extra for them.  For example, the SAP/Sybase DB's that support full in-memory can cost you from 40% to 300% more than our existing products.

So, in answer to your question, do you really need one?

Comment: I've never used MemCached. I've heard about it. I'm not 100% sure if it's the correct solution for my needs. Please see the comment to @ali haider response. As you mentioned, performance is important for me and that's why I'm not storing the data in an actual db. Secondly, since I'm fetching data from external database (using web services), it's not important for me to persist the data locally because I can always invoke the WS again. However, if I do need to perform joins and filters on data then a in-memory db may help (I think.)

Comment: So your looking for an engine that will do sorts and filters for you on a dataset that you have cached in memory.  You don't really care about a database at all, other than it has those functions built in.  That matches your question, but the title makes it sound like you want an in memory database as a cache (not as a processor).

Comment: "A in-memory database is also a database." If you agree with this statement then my question is a valid one. If not, I would appreciate if you explain what this Wikipedia article is all about. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/In-memory_database

Answer (score 0):

Try [Redisson](http://redisson.org/) - distributed and scalable familar Java data structures (Set, Map, ConcurrentMap, List, Queue, Lock, AtomicLong, CountDownLatch, Publish / Subscribe) on top of in-memory db Redis.